# Javascript created object property values undefined after calling another function with created object

Tags: javascript, function, object, properties, undefined

I know this may be a silly question but I'm new to javascript so would appreciate some guidance.

I have the following `notificationSocketEventHandler` object created:

```
const notificationSocketEventHandler = Object.create(socketHandlerProto, {
  validators: {
    created: [],
    destroyed: [],
    loadedFromSocket: [],
    updated: [],
    addedto: {
      relation: []
    },
    removedfrom: {

    }
  },
  created: function (data) {
    if (this.validateProfileData(data, validators.created)) {} else {}
  },
  destroyed: function (data) {},
  updated: function (data) {},
  loadedFromSocket: function (data) {
      console.log('Loaded from socket')
      console.log(data)
  }
})
```

This event handler is being used to listen for notifications from a socket
so and is set like this

```
$.globals.socket.on('notifications',notificationSocketEventHandler);
```

the event prototype is defined as such:

```
$.globals.socket = {
  events: {},
  on: function (attr, func) {
    if (!attr) return false
    this.events[attr] = this.events[attr] || [];
    this.events[attr].push(func)
    return true
  },
  remove(attr, func) {
    if (!events[attr]) return false

    this.events[attr].forEach(function (f, indx) {
      if (f === func) {
        events[attr].slice(indx, 1)
      }
    })
  },
  trigger: function (attr, thisArg, paramArgs) {
    if (Array.isArray(attr) && attr.length) {
      var obj = this.events[attr[0]]
      for (var i = 1; i < attr.length; i++) {
        if (!obj) return
        obj = obj[attr[i]]
      }
      if (typeof obj == 'function') obj.apply(thisArg, paramArgs)
      if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
        obj.forEach(function (c) {
          if (typeof c == 'function') c.apply(thisArg, paramArgs)
        })
      }
      return
    }
    if(this.events[attr]){
      console.log(this.events[attr])
      this.events[attr].forEach(function (f) {
        if (typeof f === 'function')
          f.apply(thisArg, paramArgs)
      })
    }
  }
}
```

The problem I am having is that after the `notificationSocketEventHandler` object gets passed to the `$.globals.socket.on` function and ultimately pushed into the events object, the properties of the `notificationSocketEventHandler` such as `created`, `destroyed`,`loadedFromSocket` which are defined as functions before being passed to the `$.globals.socket.on` function, suddenly become `undefined' once within the events object, why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object.create is a little confusing - you can't use a normal object as the second parameter, it has to be an object of 'property descriptors'. To work properly your code would need to be formatted along these lines:

```
const notificationSocketEventHandler = Object.create(socketHandlerProto, {
  'validators': {
    value: {
     'created': {
          value: []
      },
      'destroyed': {
          value: []
      },
      'loadedFromSocket': {
           value: []
      }
    }    
  }
});
```

Unless you iterate over those properties it's going to be tedious. You would be much better off avoiding Object.create and just making an object normally:

```
const notificationSocketEventHandler = {
   created: [],
   destroyed: [],
   etc...
}
```

or adding the properties to the constructor's prototype (as an aside, people usually make constructor names begin with an uppercase letter so it's immediately obvious they're constructors - saves you having to add 'Proto' at the end of the name for one thing. Anyway):

```
var SocketHandler = function {
    this.created = [];
    this.destroyed = []
    etc...
}

const notificationSocketEventHandler = new SocketHandler
```

or

```
var SocketHandler = {};
SocketHandler.prototype.created = [];
SocketHandler.prototype.destroyed = [];
etc...
```